# ASP.NET Core Web API - How to validate UserName without whitespace in between, before and after

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

In my ASP.NET Core-6 Web API, I am using Fluent Validation as shown below:

```
RuleFor(p => p.UserName)
    .NotEmpty().WithMessage("{UserName should be not empty. ERROR!");
```

I don't want any whitespace, either in between, before and after UserName. That is, I don't want to use any of these:

1. "Charley Bee"
2. " CharlerBee"
3. "Charler Bee "

How do I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the regex expression to validate space.

- `\S`: matches any non-whitespace character
- `^`: position at start of a line
- `$`: position at the end of a line

as this regex expression `^[\S]+$`

```
RuleFor(m => m.UserName).NotEmpty()
                        .Matches(@"^[\S]+$")
                        .WithMessage("{UserName should be not empty. ERROR!");
```

Comment: `"qwert"` is not passing for me. I would go with something like `@"^[^\s]+$"`

Comment: I had used my regex which might be working at  `qwert` https://regexr.com/6kn0f

Comment: Oh I see you mean non-letter

Comment: I have created simple unit test for my answer and it does not pass with provided regexes. I would guess .NET  implementation does not handle starting `/` and ending `/mg` well cause `@"^[\S]+$"` works fine for me.

Comment: I had written a test as you say .net might use `^[\S]+$` instead of `/^[\S]+$/mg` thank you for your patience to debug my regex expression

Answer (score 2):

Fluent Validation supports providing rule via [predicate](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/custom-validators.html?predicate-validator) by using `Must`:

> .Must(s => !s.Contains(' '))

```cs
RuleFor(m => m.Token)
    .Cascade(CascadeMode.Stop) // stop on first failure
    .NotEmpty()
    .WithMessage("{UserName should be not empty. ERROR!")
    .Must(s => !s.Contains(' ')) // or remove Cascade and add nullability check here
    .WithMessage("No spaces!");
```

Comment: This answer works good as well upvote